# Legends in variable radius pie Highcharts

Tags: charts, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

I want to implement variable radius pie chart in my application using Highcharts.js. But I could not find legends option in their demo example and in the documentation as well. Can anybody please help me out with how to implement legends in variable radius pie chart?
Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable legend by setting `series.showInLegend` to true.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1sctbapf/

```
series: [{
    minPointSize: 10,
    innerSize: '20%',
    zMin: 0,
            showInLegend: true,
    data: [{
        name: 'Spain',
        y: 505370,
        z: 92.9
    }, ...
  ]
}]
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.variablepie.showInLegend

Comment: Oh my bad.. I had tried this property in plotOptions, that's why it didn't work. Thank you so much for quick help! Also, Is there any property to set border to the whole pie at max value (not the individual slices) ? As i need to show how much portion of the pie slice is filled or empty. I tried color, borderColor.. But no luck. Please help if you have any idea about it.

Comment: @abhiJ I am afraid that I don't understand your requirement. Do you have a picture of the output which you want to achieve?